# Reset shell margins or output?

Tags: command-line-interface, shell, console, display

I have two problems, in both cases the problem usually occurs when I resize my terminal client xterm.

1. When ssh'd into a server all the output from commands doesn't scroll. It doesn't happen right away.
2. Occasionally the margins don't resize when the client resizes.

I have seen an article on a command to run to fix this, but I can't seem to find it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force a reset of terminal state -- `reset` command might work.  If it doesn't, send a RIS sequence to xterm -- `printf "\033c"`

Answer (score 0):

The `resize` command should fix this.  Try

```
eval `resize`
```

if you are in the bash shell (note the backticks).

Here's a [reference](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch05_05.htm).

Comment: What if the remote machine doesn't have xterm?

Comment: I think (despite what that article says) that resize works in many other shells besides xterm.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: yes. my experience says otherwise though.

Comment: ...at least on a redhat distro.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help either: shopt -s checkwinsize